# javascript function use query results

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

EDIT:
Ive edited my code a little thanks to Alexander's advice, but im still getting the problem of the contents of the div not showing, ive looked up proper closing and cant see where else or if i need to add it anywhere else in the code. My update question is, what am i missing for this to work? Thanks

I have a table which is generated from a query, in this table there is a div, i need this div to show/hide onclick, now i have a working show/hide javascript (shown below) but this only works for 1 div.

how do i modify this so that my divs with id's generated from my database ($id) can all be shown/hidden seperatly?

javascript:

```
  <script language="javascript">
    function toggle(id) {
       var ele = document.getElementById(id);
       var text = document.getElementById(id);
                 if(ele.style.display == "block") {
                 ele.style.display = "none";
                 text.innerHTML = "show";
     }
     else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
     } 
     } 
     </script>
```

html:

```
    Info: <a id='$id' href='javascript:toggle(\"$id\");'>show</a>
          <div id='$id' style='display: none'></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your generated HTML you can pass `id` value to your `toggle()` function so resulting HTML code will look like

```
Info: <a id='$id' href='javascript:toggle("$id");'>show</a>
      <div id='$id' style='display: none'></div>
```

javascript

```
function toggle(id) {
       var ele = document.getElementById(id);
       var text = document.getElementById(id);
                 if(ele.style.display == "block") {
                 ele.style.display = "none";
                 text.innerHTML = "show";
     }
     else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
     } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks but when i use this im unable to use "id" in the html as it breaks my php echo, so when i remove the " the div opens but displays nothing

Comment: @zhaobaloth do proper escaping. replace `"` with `\"` or `'` with `\'`

Comment: i now have (\"$id\") but im having the same problem, the div opens but shows nothing, i looked up proper escaping and cant see what im doing wrong, thanks

Comment: @zhaobaloth, don't worry, we can't see it either since it's on your personal machine and you haven't updated your question